# Regex - How to remove strings inside brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all words inside brackets and square brackets.
I'm using this regex, but it only removes words inside brackets. It does not work with square brackets...

```
var str = 'hey [xx] (xhini) rexhin (zzz)';
var r = str.replace(/ *\([^)]*\)*\] */g, '');
```

`r` should be `hey rexhin`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var str = 'hey [xx] (xhini) rexhin (zzz)';
var r = str.replace(/(\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)) */g, "");
//=> hey rexhin
```

- `\[.*?\]` will find square brackets and string inside them
- `\(.*?\)` will find round brackets and string inside them

You can also use (if square and round brackets are not nested):

```
var r = str.replace(/[(\[].*?[)\]] */g, "");
```

- `[(\[]` is a character class that finds `(` or `[`
- `[)\]]` is a character class that finds `)` or `]`

You can call `trim()` to trim trailing space also.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex.

```
> var str = "[xxx] hey [xx] (xhini) rexhin (zzz)";
undefined
> str.replace(/^(?:\[[^\]]*\]|\([^()]*\))\s*|\s*(?:\[[^\]]*\]|\([^()]*\))/g, "")
'hey rexhin'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yQ8lT6/2)

- `^(?:\[[^\]]*\]|\([^()]*\))\s*` would match the brackets as well as the following spaces which are present at the start (*start of the line*).
- `|` OR
- `\s*(?:\[[^\]]*\]|\([^()]*\))` Matches all the remaining brackets along with their preceding spaces.